# Difference between the "have been" and "was"

Tags: past-vs-past-perfect

An example, I want to say that I was at the zoo. How should I say that?
"I was at the zoo" or "I have been at the zoo"

Comment: Both are fine, but I might say, "I have been *to* the zoo." It is just the way I would expect to hear it and this is opinion, not grammar-police-worthy. You do need periods before the end quotes, though. :wink:

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the propriety of using the perfect is not determined by syntactic rules but by the semantic relationship of the content to the surrounding context. No context is given here, so the question cannot be answered. Take a look at questions tagged past-vs-present-perfect.

Answer (score 1):

The difference comes down to the time at which you visited the zoo, as well as the context of the conversation.

If someone is asking you if you have **ever** been to the zoo at all, it would make sense to use "I have been *to* the zoo" (use to instead of at).

If someone is asking you what you did today, or something like "Hey, where were you today?" it would make sense to say "I was at the zoo".

This is a matter of past vs. past perfect as StoneyB mentioned in comment.

Hope this helps